# indexOf running within Map function relying on Variable (array) from parent function (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Apps Script/Javascript and I'm in the midst of working on the second iteration of my original code in order to make it faster. My first code made a lot of gets and sets to the underlying Google Sheet, while now I'm trying to do everything in arrays before setting the revised values. The current block of code I'm stuck on is my attempt to run an indexOf while running a map function.

The below script is about to run through every row of an array full of timesheet data and make 
various amendments to the columns and calculate new column values.

```
var = amendedTimesheetData = timesheetdata.map(function(item){
    item.splice(2, 0, item[0] + " " + item[1]);
    item.splice(4, 0, item[0].slice(0, 2) + item[1].slice(0, 2) + date(item[3]));
    item.splice(0, 2);
    item.splice(3, 0, "Open");
    item.splice(4, 0, accountingCode); //SEE ISSUE BELOW

    return item  
  })
}
```

The accounting code variable relies on having performed a Javascript version of a vlookup based on a value in one of the array columns. The looked-up value exists in *another array* pulled from a different tab in the sheet. I know the code to perform the lookup looks like this:

```
  var timeTrackingCode = item[6]; //this is the location in the mapped array of the value to be looked up
  var timeTrackingCodeRow = codeMappingData.map(function(r){ return r[0]; }).indexOf(timeTrackingCode);
  var accountingCode = codeMappingData[timeTrackingCodeRow][1]
```

The formula in the code above relies on the **codeMappingData** variable which was made earlier in the parent function before the map function started running.

```
  var codeMappingSheet = ss.getSheetByName('CodeMapping');
  var codeMappingRange = codeMappingSheet.getDataRange();
  var codeMappingData = codeMappingRange.getValues();
```

The Question: How do I reference the **codeMappingData** array while *in* the map function?

Other options to get around this would be to run a For loop separate from the map, but while trying to learn all the possibilities I'm stuck on trying to understand how I could pass the variable through and achieve all of the column manipulations in as little code as possible. Any guidance on how I could achieve the variable pass through, or tips on how the code could be more efficient would all be very valuable. I've only copied a bit of the code, so it might lack context, but I think the question is clear.

Note that I've assumed that it would be ill-advised to establish the codeMappingData variable within the Map function because then every time it iterates through a row it would be performing a get from the sheet? If I'm incorrect in assuming this, then perhaps the simplest approach is to establish the variable within the map.

Thank you,

Comment: [Edit] to show the parent and child function as a whole with the error or  preferably a [mcve], if you aren't able to figure out the issue.

Comment: @TheMaster your explanation of scoping was correct and I code the variable references to work within the sub-function. One thing throwing me off was how the variable being referenced doesn't change color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner or child scope always has access to  variables in the outer or parent scope.

```js
function outerFunction(){
  const outerScopeVar = 5;
  const arr = [1,2,3];
  arr.map(num => {
    console.info(`I have access to both inner and outer scope variable: ${num} and ${outerScopeVar}`);
  })
}
outerFunction();
```

#### References:

- [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is helpful. I've been able to refer to a variable in a parent function from a sub function, such as when run a For Loop with sub if statements. However, I can't seem to replicate the rule you've outlined (especially having illustrated it work with Map.). The parent function `function formatTimesheets(){ }` declares variables and  runs `timesheetdata.map(function(item){})` within it. Yet variable `codeMappingData` declared in the parent function is not being recognized within the `map(function(item){})`. thisArg worked, but this restricts me to passing only 1 var

Comment: Master Thanks again for the instruction here. I simplified what I was trying to do from scratch in a new code view. What you illustrated worked and I replicated it in my original code. Understanding this has become very useful in other ways as well. To clarify - you're absolutely correct and sorry for not debugging before commenting back. Thanks again.

Comment: @Max Did you figure out why you thought `codeMappingData` was not being recognized?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `thisArg` parameter as described in the [Array.prototype.map() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Just add it after your closing curly bracket and refer to it as `this` within your map function, not `codeMappingData`.

```
var timeTrackingCodeRow = codeMappingData.map(function(r) {
  Logger.log(this[0]); // logs the first element of codeMappingData
  return r[0];
}, codeMappingData).indexOf(timeTrackingCode);
```

Comment: Thank you Diego. This solved the immediate problem and allowed me to pass the codeMappingData variable through. Can the thisArg be further used to pass multiple variables through? The illustrated example was relying on one, but what if I were performing multiple checks on different arrays/variables? Thanks again.